# Class Design in Game Programming

Tags: java, libgdx, single-responsibility-principle, open-closed-principle

I am developing a game for a company. I will only develop this game for 2 months. My company ask me to make my code clean and extendable so they can hire another programmer when they need to add more features. I have read Clean Code by Uncle Bob. I found it really hard to put some of the concept into practice. This is one of my class

```
public class MenuScreen extends ScreenAdapter {

private final Game game;

private Stage stage;
private Actor groundActor;
private Actor skyActor;
private Actor titleActor;
private Actor playbtnActor;
private Actor optionbtnActor;

public MenuScreen(Game _game) {
    this.game = _game;
}

@Override
public void show() {

    this.stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());

    createGround();
    createSky();
    createTitle();
    createPlayButton();
    createOptionButton();
    setupStage();

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this.stage);

}

public void createGround() {
    TextureRegion groundTextureRegion = Assets.instance
            .getTextureRegionByName("bg-ground");
    this.groundActor = new SRActor(groundTextureRegion);
    this.groundActor.setPosition(0, 0);
}

public void createSky() {
    TextureRegion skyTextureRegion = Assets.instance
            .getTextureRegionByName("bg-sky");
    this.skyActor = new SRActor(skyTextureRegion);
    this.skyActor.setPosition(0, 0);
}

public void createTitle() {
    TextureRegion titleTextureRegion = 
            Assets.instance.getTextureRegionByName("etc-gametitlebanner");
    this.titleActor = new SRActor(titleTextureRegion);

    int bottomLeftX = (int) ((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - this.titleActor
            .getWidth()) / 2);
    int bottomLeftY = (int) Math.floor(0.6 * this.groundActor.getHeight());
    this.titleActor.setPosition(bottomLeftX, bottomLeftY);
}

public void createPlayButton() {

    TextureRegion playbtnTextureRegion = 
            Assets.instance.getTextureRegionByName("etc-playbtn");
    this.playbtnActor = new SRActor(playbtnTextureRegion);

    int bottomLeftX = (int) (0.01 * this.playbtnActor.getWidth())
            + (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - (int) this.playbtnActor.getWidth())
            / 2;
    int bottomLeftY = (int) (this.titleActor.getY() + 0.25 * this.titleActor
            .getHeight());
    this.playbtnActor.setPosition(bottomLeftX, bottomLeftY);
}

public void createOptionButton() {
    TextureRegion optionbtnTextureRegion = Assets.instance
            .getTextureRegionByName("etc-optionbtn");
    this.optionbtnActor = new SRActor(optionbtnTextureRegion);

    int bottomLeftX = (int) (0.01 * this.optionbtnActor.getWidth())
            + (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - (int) this.optionbtnActor
                    .getWidth()) / 2;
    int bottomLeftY = (int) (this.titleActor.getY() + 0.05 * this.titleActor
            .getHeight());
    this.optionbtnActor.setPosition(bottomLeftX, bottomLeftY);

}

public void setupStage() {

    this.stage.addActor(this.skyActor);
    this.stage.addActor(this.groundActor);
    this.stage.addActor(this.titleActor);
    this.stage.addActor(this.playbtnActor);
    this.stage.addActor(this.optionbtnActor);

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    this.stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    this.stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    this.stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    dispose();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    this.stage.dispose();
}
```

}

My question is does this class violates Single Responsibility Principle? Do i need to seperate every actor to its own class? And if so how should i refactor my code?

Comment: There are a lot of game frameworks that exist (JGame is nice for 2d games). Trying to design for "extendability" the first time is very hard - bosses ask for it, but until you actually need to extend and you know in what way, you're probably making a mistake and wasting your effort. I'd suggest you look at existing frameworks, first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems okay to me. If all your different actors there have the same behaviour and are only different in their used texture, size, position etc, then having a single `SRActor` with different attributes seems appropriate.

However I would advice you to use the static factory pattern and move the generation to another class. So you would only do `stage.addActor(SRActorFactory.createOptionButton())` for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found your answer really helpful. What if I have another screen that use the same background as this? Do i need a seperate Factory or just stick with one factory. For example I have MenuObjectFactory that produce the above actors and I have another factory "OptionObjectFactory" that produce the same ground, sky and some distinct actor such as volumeSlider?

Comment: It depends a bit on how those actors that you create are grouped. You should have a Factory for a group of things that belong together, like all buttons in your main menu. But you are pretty free here and you could also put all those static factory methods into a single Factory and use that everywhere. If you can re-use those factories in many different screens, even better. Always try to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the menu screen has sky and ground (i.e. that stuff isn't part of the game), then so far so good. Looks like you have the actors in separate classes, which is good. "MenuScreen" is the sort of thing that would make sense as a single responsibility.

Comment: Just curious, won't it would be nice to keep the createGround in a separate Ground object? same goes for Sky, Title and putting related methods in relevant classes, Afa MenuScreen is concerned in that class, a construct method should be there which would construct a screen and show method will display it ?

Comment: Posting this to get more thoughts on my thinking from an experienced programmer . :) :) :)

Comment: It's just a matter of the relative importance of the objects in question. If he's just drawing sky and ground on a menu screen, then that's probably not enough to warrant distinct classes. In fact in that case I'd just grab an image and paint that on. But if the objects have special rendering logic (e.g., the sky has logic to animate clouds) then yeah, your suggestion would be entirely appropriate.

Comment: Willie Wheeler thank you very much for replying .. :) :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with libgdx and have been working on a pretty big game with a group of people. What I've found particularly useful is splitting up rendered components. For instance, I have a separate UI class for static elements. Then have a "render scene" class which hold all the dynamic components.

This isn't as prevalent in a menu. So it's hard to give a concrete example because it's sort of overkill here, but its a good practice when you start actually making core features in your game.

(input multiplexiers are a good thing to look into).

However, just making some adjusts in your code right now is why don't you create a separate "render" class for your menu? Just initialize it with the stage then add actors to it. This will allow you to add animation sequences without bloating down your `MenuScreen` class. Make it so all you have to do is do `MenuUI.render();` then it just works. Your `ScreenAdapter` should be used for transitions in your game screen not hard coding your UI. Then if you want to change the UI for your menu screen you just plug a new UI module.

Hope this helps :d

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? What would MenuUI.render() do? Call stage.render()... and you need a whole class for that?

Comment: Sorry @noone. I am new to stackoverflow. I think i can give the checklist to multiple answer. I think this is a good aternative idea for the GameScreen where there are much more Object than MenuScreen. Although i prefer creating a class for each object for the GameScreen

Comment: @progenhard Thanks for your answer. Do you mean the MenuUI is the class that have stage as the instance variable? And all the createGround(),createSky() and etc should be call when MenuUI is initialize?

Comment: @kevinyu If you do it like this, then your `MenuScreen` would be pretty useless, since it won't do anything anymore, but forward everything to `MenuUI`.